# How to optimize my "html" website speed without affecting images quality or dimensions?

Tags: javascript, html, css, performance, optimization

I have a website consists of "5 html pages" using pure (HTML , CSS , JS) no server side programming languages , frameworks or DB .

These are the speed test of my website :
https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.zhtml.aba.ae

https://gtmetrix.com/reports/www.zhtml.aba.ae/N9C8Tp0m

I know how to minify (css , js) but not (images and caching) , I was wondering if there is a way to reduce images size without affecting both [quality - dimensions] , and how to enable caching .
also if there are more tips to optimize the website speed except (images - caching - minify css and js) , please tell me what is it and how to acheive it.

**My website is responsive so i'm using images with large dimensions**

Comment: Check to make sure your serving over HTTP2 / Spdy.  These only work over SSL.  But having an SSL is always a good idea, even Google will index you less if your not.

Comment: You could try using the picture tag to optimise your image sizes for the size of screen you are serving it on.  Or try to find some software that allows you to save the images for web - this compresses them quite a lot without losing enough quality that you'd notice.  Also try keep the number of requests down - use sprites, combine js / css files.  You could also try to lazyload images (ie when they come into view). Or you could use something like webpack to help with the loading so you only load the critical above the fold files first and then the rest gets loaded in when it is needed

Comment: What server are you using (e.g. Apache, Nginx, something else)? You will need to configure it so that it uses the appropriate caching headers.

Comment: @Bergi , How to know which server?

Comment: @Joe You should know - you would have installed it. If you're renting the webspace with a managed server, ask your provider.

Comment: Don't worry about HTTP2 just yet, that's micro optimising compared to what you can gain by making the images smaller. Unless your website is about photography, compress those images. Http2 is not going to make your image smaller.

Answer (score 0):

One tool I have found extremely helpful in decreasing the file size of images is [TinyPNG](https://tinypng.com/). TinyPNG can decrease the file size of your images by up to about 80% without changing the dimensions of the image or by reducing the quality (visibly).

TinyPNG simply replaces similar colors near each other with the same color, which takes less storage.